# How to skip __mock__ folder while running strapi

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, koa, strapi

I am working on writing unit tests for API written in strapi. So I create a **mocks** folder to mock firebase API call.

[image]

This code works well when I am running the test with jest but when I run the application with `npm run develop` it gives me below error

```
[2020-06-02T12:14:58.977Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2020-06-02T12:14:58.978Z] error ReferenceError: jest is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/backend/Documents/workspace/proj/config/functions/__mocks__/firebase.js:1:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at module.exports.filePath (/home/backend/Documents/workspace/proj/node_modules/strapi/lib/load/require-file-parse.js:12:10)
    at loadFiles (/home/backend/Documents/workspace/proj/node_modules/strapi/lib/load/load-files.js:35:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! proj@0.1.0 develop: `strapi develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the proj@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/backend/.npm/_logs/2020-06-02T12_14_58_985Z-debug.log
➜  proj git:(test) ✗
```

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask I have updated the error log

Comment: I suppose the error refers to this part, https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/8ecdf63b9c959025072097e6d9bac05a963dea9e/packages/strapi/lib/load/load-config-files.js#L11-L12 . loadConfiguration allows to provide a pattern to ignore `__mocks__` but `develop` doesn't make use of this. I'd suggest to move `__mocks__` outside `config` and switch to manual mocks for it, unless you're willing to to customize `develop` script.